# split pandas dataframe by label with ratio

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that i have a dataframe contains **100 sentences** (50 spam, 50 not spam)

goal : I need to split them for **training : testing** data with ratio of **80 : 20**

which will be **80 testing data** (40 spam + 40 not spam) and **20 testing data**(10 spam + 10 not spam)

NB : im using pandas, and i need those ratio to be a variable on its own so i can change it

where im at:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': {0: 'FU bro',
  1: 'Well thats kinda cool',
  2: 'Haha thats so funny',
  3: 'cant u make somethin else mtfk',
  4: 'what a shame'},
 'label': {0: 'spam', 1: 'not spam', 2: 'not spam', 3: 'spam', 4: 'spam'}})

spam = df.loc[df['label']=='spam']
not_spam = df.loc[df['label']=='not spam']

print(spam)
print(not_spam)
#print(df.loc[df['label']=='not spam'].sum)
```

here is the header of my dataframe looks like:

| sentence | label |
| --- | --- |
| FU bro | spam |
| Well thats kinda cool | not spam |
| Haha thats so funny | not spam |
| cant u make somethin else mtfk | spam |
| what a shame | spam |

Comment: What have you already tried to do? The code you show currently only sets up a small training dataset but does nothing to attempt solving your issue.

Comment: well im trying to figure out how im suppose to split those equally first, but im having hardtime on getting how many of those spam and not spam, by using count, sum and those didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
train = df.groupby('label').sample(frac=.8)
test = df.loc[df.index.difference(train.index)]
```

Comment: Did you run this? It fails with `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sample'` because `groupby` doesn't return a dataframe.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html

Comment: Sorry, wrong alarm! Looks like my env has an earlier version of pandas `1.0.5`.

Comment: hmm this does work, but on 5 data, the testing set doesnt have the not_spam data. same as @AKS code

Comment: @AnggiaBagaskara In case of `not spam`, there are only 2 documents. If we take 80% as sample, it would return all of those and there is nothing left for testing set. Just like your big data of 100 (50 spam and 50 not spam), you could try with 10 rows (5 spam, 5 not spam) to test that these solutions work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DataFrame.sample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) for this:

```py
training_data_ratio = 0.8
train_spam = spam.sample(frac=training_data_ratio, random_state=0)
test_spam = spam.drop(train_spam.index)
```

And, similarly for the non spam data.

---

In addition, if you need to check that how many of entries are spam and not spam, you can use `value_counts`:

```py
>>> df.label.value_counts()
spam        3
not spam    2
Name: label, dtype: int64
```